# How to handle phone state in android

Tags: android

Based on these three states:

```
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
```

Is it possible to tell if there is an incoming our outgoing call?

Specifically, if there is an incoming call,

- Is there a state for when user answers the call?
- A state for when the call ends?
- Are there similar states for outgoing calls?
- Also, is there a state for rejecting a call?

Answer (score 1):

You should use your own class extending PhoneStateListener to handle when the call state changes :

```
CallStateListener callListener= new CallStateListener ();
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephony.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Then, the following code for your own class :

```
public class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d(CallStateListener.class.getSimpleName(), "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d(CallStateListener.class.getSimpleName(), "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.d(CallStateListener.class.getSimpleName(), "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a state for when user answers the call?
A state for when the call ends?
Are there similar states for outgoing calls?
Also, is there a state for rejecting a call?

Comment: For more precise receivers, you may be interested in reading this doc from Google Blog : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html and read documentation of Intents and actions : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html